# flutter:I can't load image through plugin webview_flutter

Tags: flutter

I wanna load HTML string through plugin webview_flutter, I try it like those:

But I couldn't load an image in my HTML string, meanwhile, I made WebView as a child for SizedBox, its height and width were adapted to device screen. Even though, it still exceeded device's width. I check the official demo, but it was futile

```
return WebView(
    initialUrl: '',
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
        String content = base64Encode(Utf8Encoder().convert(html));
        controller.loadUrl('data:text/html;base64,$content');
    },
);
```

Comment: .loadUrl function parameter is url, not content

Comment: in fact ,webview can support load html string ,,my code could run well now ,default webview couldn't load image starts with http,then i added "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" "in android's AndroidManifest file,you can try it.Thank you!